# Compilation error while trying to join two tables in Entity Framework LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

```
          List<VideoInfo> vobj = new List<VideoInfo>();
         vobj = (from vid in db.VideoInfoes.Where(c => c.IsActive == true)
                orderby vid.VideoId  descending
                select vid
                ).ToList();
        return View(vobj);
```

This is the orignal Query to bring the list of all the video info.
There is another table called profile which has the Profile Picture which I need along with the video Info.
So after going through an article on EF I came up with some thing like this..

```
  vobj = (from vid in db.VideoInfoes.Where(c => c.IsActive == true)
                 select new
                {
                 ProfileId = vid.ProfileId,
                 ProfilePictureUrl = vid.ProfileInfo.ProfilePictureUrl
                }
                orderby vid.VideoId  descending
                 select vid
                ).ToList();
        return View(vobj);
```

ProfileId is the foreign key. But this is not even compiling..Its showing red syntax error after the closing curly brackets and orderby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function can be corrected and made much simpler as follows:

```
return View(
   db
   .VideoInfoes
   .Where(videoInfo => videoInfo.IsActive)
   .OrderByDescending(videoInfo => videoInfo.VideoID)
   .ToList());
```

You will be able to access the `ProfileInfo` of each `VideoInfo` in the list, so long as the `db` connection is not disposed. Or you can access other `ProfileInfo` records using the `ProfileId` property in another query with another context later. It depends what you would like to do with the data; (I'm not sure what the `View` function is doing, for example.)

For example:

```
// where 'data' was what was returned from the above query
// and assuming the above 'db' connection is still open
foreach (VideoInfo videoInfo in data) 
{
   ProfileInfo profileInfo = videoInfo.ProfileInfo;

   // do something with profileInfo
}

// or if the connection was disposed:
using (MyEFModel db = new MyEFModel())
   foreach (VideoInfo videoInfo in data) 
   {
      int profileID = videoInfo.ProfileId;
      ProfileInfo profileInfo =
         db
         .ProfileInfoes
         .Single(row => row.ID == profileID);

      // do something with profileInfo
   }
```

Comment: thts true the primary - foreign key is already mapped in DB ..I dont know what was I thinking.. The previous query work's correctly ...its just that I have to go one level deep i.e.  VideoInfoModel.ProfileInfo.ProfilePictureUrl...anyways thank for all the help..

Answer (score 2):

You should do `OrderBy` before `Select` since the property you want to order is not contained in your new `select`:

```
var vobj = (from vid in db.VideoInfoes.Where(c => c.IsActive == true)
        orderby vid.VideoId  descending
        select new
            {
             ProfileId = vid.ProfileId,
             ProfilePictureUrl = vid.ProfileInfo.ProfilePictureUrl
            }
        ).ToList();
```

Aslo I feel more comfortable if using lambda syntax:

```
var vobj = db.VideoInfoes.Where(c => c.IsActive)
          .OrderByDescending(c => c.VideoId)
          .Select(c => new {
                ProfileId = vid.ProfileId,
                ProfilePictureUrl = vid.ProfileInfo.ProfilePictureUrl
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: yes I tried this.. but vobj is of type VideoInfo so its not allowing me to do ToList..It says cannot convert anonymous type to Generic type VideoInfo

Comment: @Scorpio: edited, you don't need to declare ` List<VideoInfo> vobj = new List<VideoInfo>();` since vobj is now anonymous type, use `var` instead

Comment: @Scorpio `select new` will project the sequence into an enumerable of anonymous type. If you want an enumerable of VideoInfo you should just `select vid` as you had at the end. (you don't even need a select clause if you use the method chain syntax in that case).

Comment: @CuongLe I dont get this... My view is expecting type  @ model IEnumerable<Data.VideoInfo> ...how can I use var ?? its bit confusing at this poin for me

Comment: @Scorpio: You need to take a look [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) in C#

Comment: Thanks for the concern shown.. the foreign key mapping was already set in db....I didn't think of using it correctly ....sorry